# Concat/merge xr.DataArray along an existing axis (Xarray | Python 3)

Tags: python, pandas, python-xarray

Here is a toy example but I have 2 dataframes; (1) rows=samples, cols=attributes; and (2) rows=samples, cols=metadata-fields.

I want to `concat` or `merge` to create 3-dimensional `xr.DataArray`.  I've done this multiple times but I can't figure out why it's not working in this case? I want to `concat` along the `patient_id` axis to have a 3D `xr.DataArray`.

**Why isn't `xr.concat` building the 3-dimensional `DataArray`? I think I'm incorrectly using the `dim` argument since it is supposed to `concat` along a new-axis but is there a way to do this along an existing axis?**

I'm trying to use the method from [Create DataArray from Dict of 2D DataFrames/Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36948476/create-dataarray-from-dict-of-2d-dataframes-arrays) but it isn't working. I got `merge` to work but it puts it into a `DataSet` w/ 2 data variables

```
np.random.seed(0)
patient_ids = ["patient_%d"%_ for _ in range(42)]
attr_ids = ["attr_%d"%_ for _ in range(481)]
meta_ids = ["meta_%d"%_ for _ in range(32)]

DA_A = xr.DataArray(pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((42,481)), 
                                 index=patient_ids, 
                                 columns=attr_ids), 
                    dims=["patient_id","attribute"])
DA_B = xr.DataArray(pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((42,32)), 
                                 index=patient_ids,
                                 columns=meta_ids), 
                    dims=["patient_id","metadata"])
DA_A.coords
# Coordinates:
#   * patient_id  (patient_id) object 'patient_0' 'patient_1' 'patient_2' ...
#   * attribute   (attribute) object 'attr_0' 'attr_1' 'attr_2' 'attr_3' ...
DA_B.coords
# Coordinates:
#   * patient_id  (patient_id) object 'patient_0' 'patient_1' 'patient_2' ...
#   * metadata    (metadata) object 'meta_0' 'meta_1' 'meta_2' 'meta_3' ...
xr.concat([DA_A, DA_B], dim="patient_id")
# KeyError: 'attribute'
```

Comment: I don't think you want to use `concat`. The error you are getting is telling you that `DA_B` doesn't have the `attribute` dimension. Based on what I see you trying to do, a `Dataset` with shared/aligned dimensions (patient_id, attribute, metadata) is probably what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't (yet) concatenate DataArrays with different dimensions. You need to broadcast them explicitly first, e.g.,

```
In [38]: xr.concat(xr.broadcast(DA_A, DA_B), dim="patient_id")
Out[38]:
<xarray.DataArray (patient_id: 84, attribute: 481, metadata: 32)>
array([[[ 0.5488135 ,  0.5488135 ,  0.5488135 , ...,  0.5488135 ,
          0.5488135 ,  0.5488135 ],
        ...,
        [ 0.79649197,  0.97094708,  0.95542135, ...,  0.37856775,
          0.65855316,  0.37893685]]])
Coordinates:
  * attribute   (attribute) object 'attr_0' 'attr_1' 'attr_2' 'attr_3' ...
  * metadata    (metadata) object 'meta_0' 'meta_1' 'meta_2' 'meta_3' ...
  * patient_id  (patient_id) object 'patient_0' 'patient_1' 'patient_2' ...
```

But as jhamman mentions in the comment on your question, you might actually find it easier to work with a single `Dataset` object instead, with two different variables, e.g.,

```
In [39]: xr.Dataset({'A': DA_A, 'B': DA_B})
Out[39]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:     (attribute: 481, metadata: 32, patient_id: 42)
Coordinates:
  * patient_id  (patient_id) object 'patient_0' 'patient_1' 'patient_2' ...
  * attribute   (attribute) object 'attr_0' 'attr_1' 'attr_2' 'attr_3' ...
  * metadata    (metadata) object 'meta_0' 'meta_1' 'meta_2' 'meta_3' ...
Data variables:
    A           (patient_id, attribute) float64 0.5488 0.7152 0.6028 0.5449 ...
    B           (patient_id, metadata) float64 0.2438 0.8216 0.9237 0.3999 ...
```

Comment: Thanks again @Stephan, you've been really helpful with `xarray`.  I've found ways to implement it into my everyday pipeline.  I've been trying to spread the word to the bioinformaticians I collaborate with.